# Hooke's Law: why is only one force considered?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have a question about Hooke's Law springs.

What I learned is that a Hooke's Law spring gives a force F pushing left and right and each force equals $k \cdot |l-l_o|$

Let's say there is a mass block resting on a spring on a table.  The amount of force on the mass block by the spring is thought to be $F$.  But I am thinking that that is only considering the force of the spring pushing against the block.  Shouldn't we consider the $F$ the spring is pushing against the table as well?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the setup. There's a block on top of a spring on top of a table? And the block isn't touching the table, correct?

Comment: @Shahar: it's what I understand too.

Comment: think of Newton's third law. There are 5 forces in total: weight of the block, reaction of the spring on the block [that's for the block], reaction force of the block on the spring, reaction force of the table on the spring [that's for the spring], and reaction force of the spring on the table [that's... for the table].

Comment: you're problem might also be in the unclear formulation "Shouldn't we consider the F the spring is pushing against the table as well?": consider for what?

Answer (score 2):

Consider just the spring, without worrying what the ends of the spring are connected to:

[image: Spring]

If I'm stretching the spring then I'll be applying a force $F$ to one end. But assuming the spring isn't moving, the net force on the spring must be zero. That means there must be a balancing force of $-F$ on the other end so that the net force is zero.

What Hooke's law tells us is that the magnitude of both the force $F$ and the force $-F$ are given by $k\Delta \ell$.

So we only have to consider one force, because the force at the other end is always equal and opposite.

Comment: The realization to be made is that if the spring isnt moving, Ft = 0